# Is there a good tool for drawing the layout of a mansion/manor?

Tags: tool-recommendation, map-making

I'm in the planning phase of developing a *Maid: the RPG* game, and it occurs to me that at some point I'm going to need to design the interior of a mansion.

It's a mansion that currently has four occupants; A child (the Master), a Butler (Older Man), a Chef (Polar Bear with own live-in Igloo) and pet (Giant Siberian Tiger).  At one point, it also had the master's parents, and it will need to have quarters for at least 4 Maids as well.

I don't have any problem imagining all of this, but I would like to have all the rooms of this mansion planned out, so that I can begin planning events for this game.  A few 'empty rooms' would be fine, but the main issue is that I need a way to visually represent the mansion layout.

Is there a good tool or method for drawing up the layout of a mansion/manor setting?

Qualities I am looking for are:

- Low Skill Ceiling
- Quick Results
- Free
- Multiple levels
- Clear visual representation of layout
- No signup required
- Easy to share the finished results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use something **very easy** you can use [ANAMAP](http://deepnight.net/tools/tabletop-rpg-map-editor/). It's a tool created out of frustration with too large, too complex editors with hideous, outdated pixel graphics. It only gives you an outline of your dungeon/villa/street/anything really and lots of decor etc. is abstracted by "Furniture" blue box, so it's not imposing any descriptive limits on your storytelling. If you can't learn how it works in 5 minutes, I'll be surprised. Also, it doesn't limit you to any preset rooms or themes other than keeping to a 5-foot grid.

In terms of sharing it's not ideal. While you can print and export results to PNG, saving your work requires you to save it to a .json file kept locally - it can't give you e.g. a link to a page with your design. However, if you just want to show your work, not collaborate, save a PNG and send it to your mates.

Comment: This sounds like an ideal solution.  I'll look into it tonight.

Comment: @Zibbobz Yeah, I started using it because I wanted to model modern houses and NOT dungeons, villages and starships. Ended up using it for everything all the time.

Answer (score -1):

This might not have everything you need, but it's a great tool. http://pyromancers.com/dungeon-painter-online/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include at least a basic explanation of the features you think are relevant to this question, any why you believe it is the best tool for the job.